# Js - различные способы изменения стилей элемента

Tags: javascript

Изучая js всегда натыкался на такую форму задания css стилей элементу через js `elem.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'`(1), но, решив разобраться подробнее, нашел еще два способа задания стилей:

- `elem.style['background-color'] = 'blue'`(2)
- `elem.style.setProperty('background-color','blue')`(3)

Причем у второго отличная поддержка браузерами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в 99 из 100 туториалов пишут только про изменение через точку(1).

Вообщем вопрос в том, почему так популярен (1) способ задания стилей, если (2) и (3) гораздо удобнее (оказалось не для всех)?

Comment: (1) популярен, потому что он гораздо удобнее чем (2) и (3)

Comment: `elem.style['backgroundColor'] = 'blue'` отлично применяется

Comment: @andreymal Про camelCase убрал момент, это был баг песочницы, которую использую

Comment: @andreymal Удобство - единственная причина? Тогда какой смысл в `setProperty`? Не просто так ведь этот метод добавили
Да и писать css свойства через тире привычнее, но это видимо дело вкуса

Comment: В setProperty можно передать третий параметр отвечающий за приоритет, и, судя по спецификации, это все отличие от задания стилей через точку. Окей, значит, дело вкуса + одна фича, вот и вся разница. Осталось только ответ написать

Comment: @Dantessss: ещё 2-ой и 3-ий способ отличаются от первого тем, что в параметре имени свойства можно использовать переменные. Например: `var side = 'right'; elem.style['margin-' + side] = '5px';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разницы между (1) и (2),(3) способами почти никакой. Во (2) и (3) можно передать переменную:

`var side = 'right'; elem.style['margin-' + side] = '5px';`

И немного личных препочтений.

Между (1),(2) и (3), есть еще одно небольшое различие:

`style.setProperty(propertyName, value, priority);`

В функцию можно передать третий параметр, передав в него строку `important`, получим `!important` в инлайновых стилях